# How to display crossed visual swatches for not available sizes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, template, design

I've set up a Visual swatch for sizes S, M, L. When a size is sold out I want Magento to display the sold out size with a red cross mark instead of hiding that size option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this module available for free.

https://github.com/interjar/configurable-child-visibility

Comment: Also this would help 
**Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Display Out Of Stock Products (Y/N)**
select **Yes**
and save.

Comment: @hasankhan, yes exactly, you should set out of stock to display as Yes